# Custom TypeScript type definitions file is ignored

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig, type-definition

I'm working on an Angular 9 project. I'd like to use a [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver), but since this type is currently missing from TypeScript's lib.dom.d.ts ([issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28502)), I tried to add Jason Strothmann's [ResizeObserver.d.ts](https://gist.github.com/strothj/708afcf4f01dd04de8f49c92e88093c3) file to my project.

I followed the advice given by [this](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-solutions/typescript-adding-custom-type-definitions-for-existing-libraries/) page:

1. I created a `types` directory under `src`.
2. I copied `ResizeObserver.d.ts` into `src/types`.
3. I added `"./src/types"` to the `"typeRoots"` array in `tsconfig.json` (it's in the `app` folder, just like `src`).
4. I declared an object of type `ResizeObserver` in `src/components/foo/foo.component.ts`, but TypeScript did not recognize the type, not even after stopping and restarting `ng serve`, or restarting VS Code.

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "module": "ES2015",
    "target": "ES2015",
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types", "./node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["ES2015", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  },
  "files": ["./src/main.ts"]
}
```

All other (JavaScript, DOM- or Angular-related) types are recognized by TypeScript, **only the types defined in `ResizeObserver.d.ts` are ignored**. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the problem. I had to add this line to `tsconfig.json`:

```
"include": ["./src/types/*.d.ts"]
```